Proof of a zeta function limit
At following page from Mathworld I found an interesting limit but I can not get its proof as it figures as a personal communication from B. Cloître (B. Cloître, pers. comm., Oct. 4, 2005):
$$\gamma=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\bigl(\zeta(\zeta(x))-2^x+(4/3)^x+1\bigr)$$
[eq. (36), typo $z\mapsto x$ corrected]
Could you advise me the best way to get its proof, or even better providing it directly here?
Thanks in advance

Use the expansion
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+{\cal O}(s-1),$$
hence, since $\zeta(x)=1+2^{-x}+3^{-x}+4^{-x}+5^{-x}+\cdots$, you have
$$\zeta(\zeta(x))=\frac{2^x}{1+(2/3)^x+(2/4)^x+(2/5)^x+\cdots}+\gamma+{\cal O}(2^{-x})$$
$$\qquad=2^x[1-(2/3)^x-(2/4)^x]+\gamma+R(x),$$
where $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} R(x)=0$.
The desired limit follows,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}[\zeta(\zeta(x))-2^x+(4/3)^x+1-\gamma]=0.$$
